Getting the Column Name mapping component of an EF Core Class property?
I have the following EF Core class:
public partial class myClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [Column("Team 17")]
    public bool? Team17 { get; set; }
    [Column("Team 158")]
    public bool? Team158 { get; set; }
}

I would like to iterate over the properties of this class and obtain the Column Name component of each. So, for example, for the Team17 column I would to get "Team 17". How can this be done?
I already have this code for deriving the Name of each property:
foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(myClass).GetProperties()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}


This question is similar to: Entity Framework - getting a table's column names as a string array. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In EF Core, reflection can be used to retrieve custom column names specified by the [Column] attribute on class properties. Using GetProperties() and GetCustomAttribute(), you can iterate over properties and fetch their column names, defaulting to the property name if no attribute is applied, ensuring dynamic mapping.

You can use the GetCustomAttributes method to check if each property has the ColumnAttribute attribute and retrieve it if it exists.
   foreach (PropertyInfo p in typeof(myClass).GetProperties())
    {
        var columnAttribute = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), false)
                           .FirstOrDefault() as ColumnAttribute;
    
        if (columnAttribute != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(columnAttribute.Name);
        }
        /*else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
        }*/
    }



You can find this information using built-in EF classes and methods:
using var context = new MyDbContext();
var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Entity));

var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
var columnNames = entityType.GetProperties()
    .Select(p => p.GetColumnName())
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine($"{tableName} | {string.Join(",", columnNames)}");

Advantage of this approach is that it does not checks for specified attribute and its property, but also takes under consideration configuration done through Fluent API.
